# How to configure an Ubuntu virtual server and VMWare ESXi5 the way VMWare would be able to shut it down properly?

Tags: server, power-management, vmware

I run an Ubuntu 12.04 server as a virtual machine on a VMWare ESXi 5 server.

I've configured VMWare to shut the quest machines down the sane way (with an ACPI (if I understand it righ) shutdown signal so that guest OSes would do it).

And this works with other VMs (running Windows 7 Professional and openSuSE) but doesn't work with the Ubuntu server - VMWare still offers just to power them off when I ask it to stop the guest.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

solved the problem.

Seems like installing VMware tools from VMware repositories as desctibed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools) could help as well.